# Win8 App - WCF - how to fire timer event only once?

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, windows-8, sideloading

I wrote a Win8 App which is calling a WCF every minute to get some Data. The Win8 App is shared via sideloading and i've got about 10 clients where this app is running.

So my problem is - i've got to call a special method in the WCF only every 10 minutes. But only once because this method should send Emails and i don't want them to be sent 10 times. I don't want this method to get called by every client either but have to set the timer in the win8 App. How do i set a timer who's firing his event only once every 10 minutes?

I've tried to set the timer in the WCF but it's not a good practice i guess (and it didn't work)?! And i'm also not allowed to write a windows service etc. for firing a timer event.

Am i thinking to complicated or isn't it that easy? Should i work with Backgroundthreads? Do i missunderstand sideloading? Wouldn't the timer event get fired by 10 clients every 10 minutes? I guess it would because every single client gets the other data from the WCF too.....

Comment: `but have to set the timer in the win8 App` why is that? Just set up a scheduled task on the server. Would that work?

Comment: i mean i don't have to but i'd prefer it. The customer wouldn't be happy if i do some work outside of his Win8 App or WCF. That's why i'm asking. It'd be easy for me to set up a scheduled task or a windows service.

Comment: OK, so you do *not* want to run the timer on the server but you *have* a server and a database?

Comment: OK - let me explain! I've to customize a Win8 App and a WCF for a customer. That's why i've to handle this in the WCF oder Win8 App. I'm just here for coding. I've no access to his server at all because he is publishing the wcf and the win8 app by himself.